# Upgrade to Team Foundation Server(TFS) 2017 APIs still available?

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I need to know whether if i upgrade to TFS 2017 are the APIs still available?

If so what are the APIs available on TFS 2017?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the TFS APIs are still available if you upgraded from previous version of TFS. But some of pervious APIs are obsolete. Refer to [**this link**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.teamfoundationserver(v=vs.120).aspx) to see the APIs

And new REST APIs introdcued since TFS 2015.

For available APIs on TFS, you can refer to below links:

- [Integrating with VSTS and Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/integrate/)
- [REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation
  Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview)
- [.NET client libraries for VSTS (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries)

Comment: Thank you very much Andy

Comment: Hi Andy, can i know which previous APIs are obsolete?